# deserialize a nested json string

Tags: c#, json

i have this json string

```
{
'studentinfo':
{
'name':'abc',
'age':41,
'gender':male,
 address:
{
'street':'asd',
'city':'ipd',
'state':'mah'
},
'subject':[
{
'name':'Arts','marks':40,'grade':'a'
},
{
'name':'Science','marks':40,'grade':'a'
},
{
'name':'Commerce','marks':40,'grade':'a'
}
]
}
}

class root
{
public list<studentinfo> studentinfo;
public list<address> address;
public list<subject> subject;
}

class studentinfo
{}

class address
{}

class subject
{}

JSONSerializer.ConvertFromJSON<root>(JSONData)
```

i want to deserialize the above json string but am getting null values? Any idea where it is incorrect?

```
  public static T ConvertFromJSON<T>(String json)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return serializer.Deserialize<T>(json);
    }
```

[image: json]

Comment: can u please elaborate why it was down voted?? you could have commented here instead of down voting in return i would have understood where am wrong posting this question?

Comment: the json string is perfect in real scenarios i have just posted reference structure same as the json structure am using

Comment: Have a look at [this article](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/02/NET-35-JSON-Serialization-using-the-DataContractJsonSerializer.aspx) it could help

Comment: What are you currently using to deserialize it (that is giving null values)?

Comment: Try to validate your JSON: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @codeulike i have posted my deserializers code

Comment: its perfect i checked out at jsonlint already

Comment: Some parts are not quoted (male, address), others are quoted with ', instead of ", this is definitely not a "perfect json string". Make sure it's correct before trying. Jsonlint says "Parse error on line 1: ..." - how did you check it exactly?...

Comment: as i have already commented this json string i have posted has just the structure of the original json am using in my code, which i havent posted here. just wanted to know how to deserialize such a nested json string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to change your classes like this:

```
class root
{
    public root()
    {
    }

    public studentinfo studentinfo { get; set; }
}

class studentinfo
{
    public studentinfo()
    {
        subject = new List<subject>();
    }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }

    public address address;
    public List<subject> subject;
}

class address
{
    public string street { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
}

class subject
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int marks { get; set; }
    public string grade { get; set; }
}
```

and there's an error with your JSON

```
'gender':male,
```

should be

```
 'gender': 'male',
```